# How to get a value from Json result

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs4

This is the json result I get from my controller

```
{"data":"Sunday"}
```

The data can say any day of the week (Sunday, Monday, etc...)

On success I want to do this in ajax call

```
success: function(Response){
        var myresponse = Response.data;
        alert(myresponse);
}
```

However, it gives me undefined.

Comment: Are you sure thats the value being returned? What does `console.log(Response.data);` give you?

Comment: If you are sure data is returned.. Did you try using Ext.JSON class?

Comment: I am looking into that now Abdel... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you are getting a JSON response from the server, you can make use of the [Ext.JSON](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.JSON) class to decode the JSON.

You can use the `decode()` method to convert a string to an object. Then you should be able to easily access it.

Example:

```
var jsonObject = Ext.JSON.decode(Response.responseText);
var myData = jsonObjet.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery to load this string you could just use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which will automatically parse the string and pass the object as the return value to the 'success' function.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a

```
console.log(Response);
```

to check the content of Response

Comment: on alert(Response) it gves me [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

It might be considering your response to be a string. I would do something like this:

```
success: function(Response){
        alert(typeof Response);
        var myresponse = Response.data;
        alert(myresponse);
}
```

If it tells you that Response is  string, you need to make sure that your framework knows you are getting back JSON. For instance with jquery it might be $.getJSON().

Comment: the first one gave me object and then the second one undefined